# 'SQL command not properly ended' error in one database but not the other, using the same script to create sequence

Tags: database, oracle, sequence

I am trying to create a sequence in DUAL.
The script is as follows:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE "SEQ_DummyID"  MINVALUE 1000000 MAXVALUE 9999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1000000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  GLOBAL' ;

COMMIT;
END;
```

The script works in one database in one database but not the other.
The error I'm getting is:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

With no syntax changes, why am I getting this error?

Comment: Probably older version? In [Oracle 11](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) 'NOKEEP' does not work. In [Oracle 12](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm#SQLRF01314) it works.

Comment: `"SEQ_DummyID"` isn't a good name for a database object, as you will have to use exactly the same case and quotes every time you use it. It would be better to use standard case-insensitive naming e.g. `SEQ_DummyID`.

Comment: From 12.1 onwards you can use [identity columns](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1) and stop micromanaging sequences.

Answer (score 2):

If you just remove the part `NOSCALE`, you can create your sequence, provided you're using version `12c`(*at least does not work for 12c Release 1* )

> *Scalable sequences have been available since the first release of Oracle 12c(designed to fix issues related with sequence generated primary keys during huge loads  ), 
>   but they were not documented and therefore not supported.
>   They are included in the documentation for the first time in Oracle
>   18c.*

[and works in 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=95cdcc917d06dc053f6aee159e765437)